# Hopital: $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x-\tan^{-1}\:x}{x^3}\right)$

Tags: calculus

Using L hopitals rules  to find the limit with full working lhopital:
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x-\tan^{-1}\:x}{x^3}\right)$$

Comment: What have you tried? Show your attempt!

Answer (score -1):

Notice that by plugging in $x=0$ you get the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$, so we can apply the l'Hopital:

\begin{equation*} lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x-tan^{-1}(x)}{x^3}=lim_{x \to 0}  \dfrac{(x-tan^{-1}(x))'}{(x^3)'}=lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}{3x^2}=\frac{1}{3} \end{equation*}